# Update local php file from remote php file

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I am working on a CMS that will be installed for many clients, but as I keep on improving it I make modifications to a few files. I want these updates to be automatically applied to all the projects using the same files.

I thought of executing a check file every time the CMS is opened. This file would compare the version of the local file with the remote file, for this I can keep a log or something for the versions, no big deal, but that's not the problem, here is some sample code I thought of:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/myfile.php';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

The problem is getting the content of `myfile.php` since its a PHP file the server will execute it and return the output, but I want the actual content of the file. I understand that this is not possible as it would be a security problem, anybody would be able to get the php code of other sites, but is there any way to get the contents of a remote php file maybe by giving special permissions to a remote connection?

Thanks.

Comment: You should create a download script on your server which uses readfile() to read and output the file contents. Call this scripts with a filename from your local server, like http://remote.tld/download?file=anyFileYouNeed.php

Comment: great idea!!! add it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a download script on your remote server which will return the original php code by using readfile().

```
<?php
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_GET['file'];

// @TODO: Add security check if file is of type php and below document root. Use realpath() to check this.
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"");
readfile($file);
?>
```

Get file contents by fethcing `http://example.com/download.php?file=fileName`